# How do I sync and share Calendars from multiple Google accounts with my phone?

Tags: sync, google-account, google-calendar

I have some questions regarding to Android's default calendar app in Galaxy 5 (five).

1. I am working with two Google accounts, but my calendar app shows calendar of only one account which is marked default. How to see events in calendar of other account?
2. How can I sync events of Android calendar and Google's online calendar?
3. How can I share events of my calendar to other Android device or my friend's Google calendar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you upgraded your Galaxy 5 to Android 2.2, you can do the following:

1. To sync and see calendars from both accounts:
   **a.** If you already added your other GMail account, skip to step **c.**
   **b.** Add your second GMail account under `Menu -> Settings -> Accounts & sync -> Add account -> Google` and follow directions there.
   **c.** Tap on the newly added account and make sure the "Sync Calendar" option is selected and exit out of Settings.
   **d.** Open up the Calendar app and go to `Menu -> More -> Calendars` expand the newly added Google account, which should show you all of its available calendars.  Keep tapping the button  to the right of each calendar until both icons are enabled, and the text under the account name reads "synced, visible", and tap the OK button.
   **e.** You should now be able to view the second calendar's entries in the Calendar app (or any app that accesses Google calendars.)
2. Any events you create on your phone via the Calendar app and assign to a GMail account will automatically sync to your online GMail account.
3. Instructions for sharing your Google Calendar with a friend can be found [here](http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?answer=37082).

Comment: Chank, here in India we don't have any official upgrades from samsung and I don't want to void my warranty. So my phone is still in 2.1... :-(

Comment: I can't remember if 2.1 allows multiple GMail accounts or not.  If it does, then the idea is the same, only the menus are slightly different.  In either case, my answers to your questions 2 and 3 still apply.